# Difference between android.os.Handler and java.util.logging.Handler?

Tags: android, handler

Question pretty much sums it. I mistakenly import the java.util.logging and don't get the desired functionality . Now i solve my problem but i want to know why android has created two Handler . We can mistakenly import the wrong one. Same as it did with Fragment and Support Fragment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

### android.os.Handler:

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue.

From [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html):

### java.util.logging.Handler

> A Handler object takes log messages from a Logger and exports them. It
>   might for example, write them to a console or write them to a file, or
>   send them to a network logging service, or forward them to an OS log,
>   or whatever.
>
> A Handler can be disabled by doing a setLevel(Level.OFF) and can be
>   re-enabled by doing a setLevel with an appropriate level.Handler
>   classes typically use LogManager properties to set default values for
>   the Handler's Filter, Formatter, and Level

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.logging.Handler` comes from vanilla Java. It is a superclass to various types of logging endpoint (socket, file ...)

`android.os.Handler` is a class created by the android development team to handle messages.

There are other examples:

- Apache DateUtils and Android DateUtils
- `java.lang.Integer` and `android.R.integer`

...

As long as classes are in different packages, it is allowed for them to have the same name. (And it is inevitable, too, as people are bound to use the same name to refer to vaguely similar things)

Answer (score 1):

A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

A Handler object accepts a logging request and exports the desired messages to a target, for example, a file, the console, etc. It can be disabled by setting its logging level to Level.OFF.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

[android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

**Example:** If you want to execute some action on UI thread.
This is available in android API only

[java.util.logging.Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html)

A Handler object takes log messages from a Logger and exports them. It might for example, write them to a console or write them to a file, or send them to a network logging service, or forward them to an OS log, or whatever.

**Example:** Want to write output somewhere that is not handled by provided handler, create your own handler and hook with logger. Logs will be written by your provided handler.

There is a huge difference. Calling a class Handler doesn't imply they all work same. Handler carry out task provided to them. It can be logging, or in case of android its the execution of some task.

Comment: to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own  Explain it.

Comment: Like executing on UI thread. Read this article (specifically "Define a Handler on the UI Thread" part) https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html